# Can no longer choose the initial location of new projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I used to be able to click on Create New Project -> Other Languages -> Visual C# -> Windows Form Application and this would show:

Name: ______

Location: C:\Users\NAME\source\repos

Solution name: _______

Though now when trying to create a project it's showing:

Name: ______

Framework: ______

I like to choose the location of each new project and I'm not sure why it's not showing anymore. It works on my laptop but not my desktop.

Edit: So since this works on my laptop I looked at the version and it was Enterprise not Community which my desktop has. So I installed Enterprise on my Desktop but I still don't have the optio..

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (Version 15.6.5) and I can select the location. What version are you using?

Comment: @Andrew Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.6.6) on my desktop. I haven't checked my laptop yet.

Edit: turns out my laptop is using Enterprise. So I guess only Enterprise has it.

Comment: Alright so I installed Enterprise but I still don't have the option. Not sure why.

Comment: If you go to Help / About Microsoft Visual Studio, does it say Enterprise? Do you have both versions coexisting?

Comment: @Andrew Yes I have both versions on this computer and both do not have the location option. Though on my laptop with the exact same versions I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must go to Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / General, and make sure "Save new projects when created" is checked.

[image: Save new projects when created]

Comment: Thanks! It really bugs me when I can't choose the location right away because my college class wants us to put certain things in certain folders + I believe I have slight OCD.